# Authlogic with sinatra?

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra, authlogic

I couldn't find resources on how to use [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) with [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). Or at least no documentation about a *canonical* way to do authentication with authlogic ...

Anyone has pointers to some tutorials, sample code or can sketch out a minimal authlogic/sinatra example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to check this out http://github.com/ehsanul/Sinatra-Authlogic-Template :)

good luck

Answer (score 2):

Authlogic is written for Rails. The vast majority of its code is dependent on specific Rails components which are not easily duplicated in Sinatra (like controllers). While it's *possible* to use Authlogic with Sinatra it would take a ton of work and I don't think it's the right approach. A lightweight web framework should use a lightweight authentication mechanism. Take a look at the [sinatra-authentication](http://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication), which is well-documented, has some similar features to Authlogic, and is almost as easy to use.

Comment: from the authlogic docs it sounded like a quite framework agnostic plugin; that's why i asked this question; anyway .. thank you for your answer

Comment: Totally reasonable question--that first sentence in the Authlogic README is a little misleading.

Comment: "Authlogic can be used in any ruby framework you want: Rails, Merb, Sinatra, Mack, your own framework, whatever." -- http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic